# Как удалить узел в xml по имени?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Есть xml

```
<JOBS>
  <job ID="1" CheckForScan="True"  /> 
  <job ID="2" CheckForScan="True"  /> 
  <settings Read="True"  /> 
</JOBS>
```

Как с помощью Linq удалить все узлы с именем job?

Comment: xDocument.Element("JOBS").Elements("job").Remove();

Comment: какой тип у xDocument? Можешь написать более подробнее?

Comment: XDocument xDocument = new XDocument(new XElement("JOBS", new XElement("job", new Attribute("ID","1"))....);

Comment: это пример точно рабочий?

Comment: XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
                xd.Load(pathToXML); Я считываю данные из документа. А дальше хочу удалить некоторые узлы.

Comment: using System.Xml.Linq;
...
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(pathToXml);
xDoc.Element("JOBS").Elements("job").Remove();

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Оформи как ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: Может подскажешь тоже? Если есть необходимость дописать узел job. Каким образом это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
...

//Удаление всех job элементов из первого узла
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(pathToXml);
xDoc.Element("JOBS").Elements("job").Remove();

//Добавление 
xDoc.Element("JOBS")
    .Add(new XElement("job",
                      new XAttribute("ID", "newOne"),
                      new XAttribute("CheckForScan","True")));
```